# add summary `n` from one dataframe to another dataframe (tidyverse)

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I was wondering if there might be a way to replace the column `fpc` in `DATA2` with corresponding `fpc` obtained from `DATA1`?

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/d/master/su.csv')

## 10000 rows ################
 DATA1 <- dat %>%
    group_by(across(all_of(c("gender", "pre")))) %>%
    summarise(n = n(), .groups = 'drop') %>%
    mutate(fpc = n/sum(n)) %>% 
    right_join(dat)


dat2 <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/d/master/out.csv')
  
## 200 rows #################
DATA2 <- dat2 %>%
  group_by(across(all_of(c("gender", "pre")))) %>%
  summarise(n = n(), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  mutate(fpc = n/sum(n)) %>% 
  right_join(dat2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the dataframe and use `coalesce` to select `fpc` from `DATA2`.

```
library(dplyr)

result <- DATA2 %>%
           left_join(DATA1 %>% distinct(gender, pre, fpc), 
                     by = c('gender', 'pre')) %>%
           mutate(fpc = coalesce(fpc.y, fpc.x)) %>%
           select(names(DATA2))

nrow(result)
#[1] 200
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222578/discussion-on-answer-by-ronak-shah-add-summary-n-from-one-dataframe-to-another).

Answer (score 1):

It would be more efficient to do this in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DATA2)[as.data.table(unique(DATA1[c('gender', 'pre', 'fpc')])),
            fpc := i.fpc, on = .(gender, pre)]
```